# About typescript with es6. What I do, please?

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this error:

> [0] app/components/pessoas/detail/PessoaDetailComponent.ts(27,35): error TS2339: Property 'pessoa' does not exist on type '{}'.

Code:

```
   export class PessoaDetailComponent
   {
    pessoa: any;

    constructor(private _api: Api, private _params: RouteParams)
    {
        this._api.getPessoa(_params.get("id")).then(
            (res) => {
     //line 27//     this.pessoa = res.pessoa;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
         )
      }
   }
```

Comment: What does res.pessoa return? Which type of value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type related issue. For whatever reason, typescript thinks `res` is of type `{}` and thus complains that `pessoa` doesn't exist on the type

use

```
(res: any) => {
  this.pessoa = res.pessoa;
},
```

or use the appropriate type if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to chain methods on a promise inside a constructor. Don't do that. Your `this` instance is getting messed up due to the promise.

```
constructor(private _api: Api, private _params: RouteParams)
{
    this.pessoa = this._api.getPessoa(_params.get("id"));
}
//anywhere you need to use the pessoa property use this.pessoa.then()
```

Comment: Or reference `this` in the old JS way :(